# qemu guest is bypassing host's firewall

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, firewall, qemu, nat

I've got a Ubuntu host running several virtual machines using `qemu-kvm`.

Every guest should use our local DNS server, so I blocked outgoing DNS requests using `ufw` on the host machine:

```
sudo ufw deny out dns
```

It's working on the host fine and something like this won't work:

```
dig stackexchange.com @8.8.4.4
```

However from guests, everyone can use any DNS servers they like. Actually I can see the packets going through the host to 8.8.4.4 without being blocked by host and the response being received by the guests.

The guests are using NAT as their network configuration, and I'm wondering is this how NAT works or I'm missing something else here?

Comment: `ufw deny` applies only to locally originating or terminating traffic, not forwarded traffic such as to your VMs. You probably need a different firewall manager, other than `ufw`. You also should be using virt-manager instead of manually creating VMs. Libvirt has its own network filter which can block such traffic.

Comment: Depending on how you configured networking with with qemu-kvm, packets may or may not get forwarded by the host, and if they are not forwarded, they won't go through the iptables FORWARD chain and can't be filtered. So make sure you get a tun/tap interface in the host for each VM, setup the host to forward packets (and masquerade if necessary), and *then* you can add the correct filtering rules (with `iptables` if `ufw` can't do that).